# Reactor Sink multiple consumers. Make Sink#emitNext block while all are busy?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a Reactor Sink with 4 concurrent consumers for a workload of type `T`.

Whenever work is produced and `sink.emitNext(T)` is called, I want the work to be executed on one of the available consumers. **When all consumers are busy the `sink.emitNext(T)` call should block** until the first consumer is available.

`sink.emitNext(T)` can be called from various places and threads.

How would I set something like that up?

```
Sinks.Many<T> sink = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer(new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1));

...

sink.asFlux()
    .flatMap(work -> doTheWork(work), 4)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
    .subscribe();

...

sink.emitNext(message, (signalType, emitResult) -> emitResult.equals(Sinks.EmitResult.FAIL_OVERFLOW));
```

This works, except that it accepts 1 additional call of `sink.emitNext(T)` without blocking which goes into the queue. I feel I need a "size-0 queue" to make this work, but not sure how to do that.

I tried a `new SynchronousQueue<>()` instead, which does allegedly that, but that blocks the whole system the first time `sink.emitNext(T)` is called.